# How to construct table in postgreSQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
 __tablename__ = "user_ingredients"
ingred_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredients.ingred_id'), nullable=False)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'), nullable=False)
```

ingred_id and user_id are variables in the class UserIngredient. How do i create the table user_ingredients in postgreSQL as im not sure how to do it when its like ingredients.ingred_id. On searching internet something about foreign keys was mentioned but this is first time im using postgreSQL so i dont know how to use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a basic M:M relationship between tables USERS and INGREDIENTS. The table USER_INGREDIENTS the is the resolution between them. Any additional attributes then describe the particular attributes for a specific combination of user and ingredient.

```
create table users( user_id integer generated always as identity 
                  , name text 
                  --other columns 
                  , constraint users_pk primary key (user_id) 
                  ); 
                 
create table ingredients( ingredient_id integer generated always as identity 
                        , name text 
                         --other columns 
                        , constraint ingredients_pk primary key (ingredient_id) 
                        );                  

create table user_ingredients( user_id integer 
                             , ingredient_id integer  
                             , quantity number                   -- for example
                             , measurement_type text             -- for example
                             , quantity_description text         -- for example 
                             , constraint user_ingredients_pk 
                                          primary key (user_id, ingredient_id) 
                             , constraint user_ingredients_2_user_fk 
                                          foreign key (user_id)
                                          references users(user_id) 
                             , constraint user_ingredients_2_ingredients_fk 
                                          foreign key (ingredients_id)
                                          references ingredients(ingredients_id)
                             ); 
                  );
```

As indicated the above is pretty basic to any relational database. I suggest you invest some time ( references and tutorials) understanding them, even if you will only work with teem through an obfuscation (ORM) layer.